# Arquivos Css e js não carregam em produção

Tags: angular, deploy, build

Olá,

Ao fazer o deploy da minha aplicação em um servidor **tomcat 8.5** os arquivos css e js importados no **angular.json** não são carregados. localmente funciona corretamente

**Observações:**

Esse servidor possui um link para acesso externo, quando eu acesso a aplicação passando o IP do servidor na url o css e js são carregados, porém com o link de acesso externo o Css e js não são carregados.

Eu utilizo o base `href="/Projeto"`, e no `angular.json` defino os caminhos da seguinte forma :

```
"node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
"src/styles.css",
"node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css",
"node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"src/bootstrap3/bootstrap3.min.css",
"node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
"node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
"node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css"
```

Eu já tentei:

Fazer o build do projeto com a `config --extract-css=false`
e também já mudei esse atributo para false no `angular.json`

Observações 2:

Ao inspecionar a página foi possível ver que o arquivo acontece um erro

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

E esse erro indica que foi no `styles.e7efefb7ef5355459826.js:1`

Eu fiz o build de produção, e reforçando, esse erro só acontece acessando o link externo para o meu servidor

Comment: Você fez o build de produção ou desenvolvimento?

Comment: Oi Guilherme, Fiz o build de produção

Comment: Olha, já vi dificuldade assim para visualizar formatação em produção e por incrível que parece o problema era o cache do navegador. Cache, cookies, e histórico. Limpei tudo e foi.

Comment: Valeu Fabiano, fiz o teste, não foi isso, também tentei navegadores diferentes e maquinas diferentes, lembrando que esse erro acontece quando eu acesso o link externo do servidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que estava causando o erro em produção foi o CSS do fonte awesome, que por algum motivo que ainda não sei, não funcionava em produção e fazia com que todo o resto do CSS não fosse carregado.

Parei de importar o mesmo no angular.json e fiz o import no Index através de cdn e tudo passou a funcionar

Answer (score 0):

tentou usar o seguinte comando:

ng build --base-href /Projeto/ --output-path=./Projeto

você usará o --output-path informando o caminha de onde quer salvar a build com nome da  Projeto, dai você sobre para o servidor esta pasta e testa se funcionou.

Comment: Oi Luis, obrigado pela resposta. Na verdade eu já faço desse jeito que mencionou.
Lembrando que esse erro só acontece acessando pelo link externo